# How can `.toPrecision()` method knows the 16°, 17° and 18° digits of PI?

Tags: javascript, math, pi

How can `.toPrecision()` method knows the 16°, 17° and 18° digits of PI?

```js
var x = Math.PI;
console.log(x);

var y = new Number(x);
console.log( y.toPrecision(19) );
```

Comment: Actual pi value is `3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582...` so the `3.141592653589793116` approximation is *wrong*

Comment: It doesn't; the digits you're getting are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Actual PI value is

> 3.141592653589793**238**46264338327950288419716939937510582...
>
> 3.141592653589793**116**

and the Javascript approximation is just *wrong*. No magic: `.toPrecision()` doesn't know 16, 17, 18th digits of PI.

Answer (score 1):

When you truncate π to 51 bits after the decimal point (corresponding to the fraction `7074237752028440`/`2251799813685248`), you get the value

```
3.1415926535897931159979634685442...
```

which seems to match (with rounding).

51 is the number of significant bits remaining in the double-precision floating-point representation after you deduce the integer part (the mantissa has 53 bits).